# Exit interactive console in Jupyter notebook using the q library to debug

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter

I've just tried to use the `q` library in a Python Jupyter notebook to debug a function. That put me right in interactive console mode to debug.

But now I can't exit the interactive console mode. I tried the obvious ones: `q`, `exit()`, `quit()` but none of them works.

What is the right command?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but in q exit with: `exit 0`